# How do I edit an edit that is still in peer review?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, editing-help

Say, I've edited a question asked by someone. I submitted my edit, and then realize I could have made few more changes. Now I want to edit my previous edit. How can this be done? (If it can be done?)

Comment: @Arjan : If I could "Accept" what you have done, I'd definitely have :) 

"Action spoke louder than words" :) Thanks ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At your rep level on main, your edits go into an edit queue; while there, your edits can be voted up/down, and if two votes go either direction, your edit is either incorporated or not.

Until your edit is committed or rolled back, the post is pretty much locked for others. (Some people, >3000 rep?, can hit the `Improve` button, but only if they don't hit the `Accept` or `Reject` button first.)

So you'll just have to wait until the edit is `Accepted` or `Rejected`, and then make more edits. Kinda slow, but I've never seen *simple* edits (code formatting, fixing broken links, fixing broken grammar) outstanding longer than 30 minutes, and more complicated edits that involve knowing *details* of specific programming languages or APIs are still no worse than an hour or so.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done if you, within a short period after submitting the edit (5 minutes, I believe),  just press `edit` again and submit the edit before the short period ends. The 6 character threshold does not apply in the short period.

**Update**: I found empirically that if there is any period it is longer than 5 minutes. There may not be a time limit.

Comment: I don't think it matters how long is between the edits as long as the any edit still in the queue is yours. A couple of weeks ago I made 2 edits to the same question over an hour apart and because it was not reviewed until after the second, the combined result appeared as a single change in the post's history.