# Bring up original edit summary when editing your prior edit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits, edit-summary

**EDIT:**  It seems that I've also had edits that stacked well, so I'm not sure if I had a timing problem, or was just delusional.  The one thing that can be fixed, that I'll turn this question into, is **a feature request so that when I go to re-edit (either within the 5-minute grace period, or before a suggested edit is approved), it brings up the old edit summary text**.  Right now, it brings up a blank edit summary, and this replaced the first one I did.  This isn't really intuitive, and even knowing that's what it's doing, I still forget to put everything in.

**Original Question:**

*It has happened a few times now, when on a site where I don't have edit privileges, that I make an edit.  I then see that the edit didn't work quite right, so I go back in to re-edit it.  This creates a brand new edit review, with an additional useless summary.
How about we have the same grace period to re-edit your up-for-review edit, as there is for a normal edit?

Of course, it wouldn't be possible once it's been approved.*

Comment: I've... revised my own edits on Game Development several fold. Well after the grace period, in one case, and they don't cause multiple edit suggestions. How are you doing it, exactly?

Comment: @Grace, I just hit the edit button (before my first edit has been approved) and then I have to redo all of my edits and re-submit.

Comment: Very curious... that's what I do, too, but I don't have to re-do all of my edit content. I'm running a test right now on Game Development. I'll see if it produces additional suggestions.

Comment: @Grace, I just tested again on WebApps and confirmed the results, let me know if Game Dev is different.

Comment: Well, my test within the 5 minute period confirms *my* results - all of the content of my edit is still there, and my new edit summary replaced the one I originally provided. I've got a theory about the discrepancy between your results and my results, but I want to do one last edit after the grace period just to confirm something else.

Comment: @Grace, I wonder if your mod status from other sites changes anything?

Comment: @Lance Roberts: I have observed the same as Grace Note (also within the last week). See [How do I edit an edit that is still in peer review?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87443/how-do-i-edit-an-edit-that-is-still-in-peer-review/87465#87465). In addition, there is no grace period.

Comment: Yeah, mine works after the grace period as well, like Peter's answer suggests. Out of curiosity, Lance, are you submitting edits *anonymously*, or as a registered user of the target site? That's my only theory of the discrepancy I can come up with right now, as it may be the fact of not tracking *where* an anonymous edit comes from, compared to when the edit comes from a registered user. I don't think moderator status has an affect, as Peter Mortensen is not a moderator.

Comment: @Peter, it's lets me do another edit and only one comes out the other end (though I don't know what the edit approver sees), but when I go to re-edit, it makes me start all over.

Comment: @Grace, yeh, I'm signed in.

Comment: That shoots my theory out of the water, then. I've made 3 edits to the same post in a greater-than-5-minute period, it pretty much behaved exactly like editing a grace period with 2k+. Hm... curious. What browser/OS, in case it affects it?

Comment: @grace, ok, another try, this time it came up with what I'd edited before, so I was just able to make the small additional change.  I'll do more experimenting when I can.  Though it still makes me put in a new summary, I'll watch this one close to see what the summary ends up as.

Comment: @grace, looks like only the 2nd edit summary counts

Comment: @grace, ok, not sure what the anomaly was, but I've changed the question.

Comment: The "have to re-enter the edit summary" is the same behavior as with normal edits, so I might suggest expanding your request as such (if not ensuring that said request does not already exist).

Comment: @Grace, edited it accordingly.  I guess I never noticed before because I don't leave a lot of edit summaries, only when I do something that needs explanation.

Comment: Working on this now - I've refunded your bounty, because the most valuable commodity on Earth is Meta Rep :)

Comment: @Jarrod, thanks, it does my heart good to see __status-planned__, and an extra 100 rep.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The previous edit comment will now be retained when:

- an error has been detected during an edit submission
- the current user is [quick editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work/21789#21789) within the 5 minute threshold
- anyone is editing a pending suggested edit

This will be deployed tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Quick editing appears to have a regression; if I re-edit a post within 5 minutes, the Edit Summary field is empty again.

Comment: This is not intuitive. Even if it prefills the field with the last summary, instinctively I'll fix it to be what I'm really doing when another edit. It should either tell the user what is happening, or concatenate all of the edit summaries.