# Please auto-merge edit-summary on edit merge

Tags: feature-request, edits, edit-summary

Often this happens to me:

- I see a poorly formatted question.
- I format the question, rename, retag, describe my deeds concisely in the [edit-summary](/questions/tagged/edit-summary) field.
- I submit.
- I realise the bloody prettifier won't deduce the correct language automatically.
- I edit again, adding a language hint. Putting `lang-hint` into the [edit-summary](/questions/tagged/edit-summary).
- I submit again, my two consecutive edits are merged into one, and its summary is `lang-hint`. Which is wrong, I did more than that.

The above may obviously come in different shapes.
The point is: if auto-merging two consecutive edits of the same person, please apply some logic and either boldly concatenate the summary, or `diff` the two summaries to see what's to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for this is already planned as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93164/bring-up-original-edit-summary-when-editing-your-prior-edit).